# Get ApplicationName from packageName

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to insert the name of the application as a summary of preference. I wrote this code but it does not work because when I run the application crashes with a NullPointerException in this line

```
name.setSummary(Pm.getApplicationLabel(nameApp));
```

The code is

```
    value2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("ApplicationName");

    PackageManager Pm = getPackageManager();

    ApplicationInfo nameApp = Pm.getApplicationInfo(value2, 0);

    name.setSummary(Pm.getApplicationLabel(nameApp));
```

Value2 is the name of a variable that takes the name of the package went from a previous Activity and this step works well, in the sense that the name of the package is properly passed and recovered

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
    PackageManager packageManager=this.getPackageManager();
    List<ApplicationInfo applist=packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0);


    Iterator<ApplicationInfo> it=applist.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        ApplicationInfo pk=(ApplicationInfo)it.next();

        String appname = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(pk).toString();
        System.out.println("Application name : "+appname);
    }
```

Or particular package name

```
final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(PackageName, 0);
} catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
    ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
System.out.println("Application name : "+applicationName);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this method, for the package

```
Resources appR = ctx.getResources();
CharSequence txt = appR.getText(appR.getIdentifier("app_name",
"string", ctx.getPackageName()));
```

and for the application name use `PackageManager#getApplicationInfo()`